# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named '<Directory name>'

Tags: python, python-3.x

When I call `python __main__.py`

I receive error:

> from facebook.fb_api import FacebookApi
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'facebook'

```
  # __main__.py

from facebook.fb_api import FacebookApi   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = FacebookApi()
    api.start()
```

Project structure

```
facebook/
├── cache.py
├── configs.py
├── fb_api.py
├── __init__.py
├── __main__.py
├── parser
│   ├── cfg.py
│   ├── example.json
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── models.py
│   ├── run_parser.py
│   └── utils.py
├── __pycache__
│   └── fb_api.cpython-36.pyc
├── request_handler.py
└── services
    ├── case_service.py
    └── __init__.py
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `fb_api.py` is in the same directory as `__main__.py` so no `facebook` folder exists for your application. Remove it from your import and it should work

Comment: Yes, it works.
But how can i use  this name ```facebook.fb_api```?

Comment: Just move the `__main__.py` file outside from the `facebook` directory

Comment: If you want to use `facebook.fb_api`, it means you are thinking of your facebook folder as a module. So, it doesn't make sense to have your `__main__.py` inside it, as you are trying to import your "library"

Answer (score 0):

Because `__main__.py` is in the same directory. So just import `fb_api`. To use `Facebook.fb_api` then move **main**.py to Facebook directory.

Answer (score 0):

You need to run your code from a higher level in your directory structure. Rather than running from within the `facebook` folder, run from its parent folder with `python -m facebook`. The `-m` flag tells Python you're running module by its Python name, which in this case is the `facebook` package. A package being run that way has its `__main__.py` file run as the main script, which is exactly what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Try local import

```py
  # __main__.py

from .fb_api import FacebookApi   

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api = FacebookApi()
    api.start()
```